# How to append a list Item to an ol in twig after rendering?

Tags: php, symfony, hook, twig, template-engine

I want to write a listener that listens for the event in symfony that runs after the controller has returned its response so that i can modify the view using twig. for ex. I would like to append a custon li element to an already filled out ol element that was filled out by the controller. Is it to late to use Twig at this point and i have to load the response of the controller into a DomDocument and change it from there or does Twig have native ways of "Hooking" into the view so to speak. I would rather use something OOP based like dom.GetElementById(x) and not something like str_replace etc

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look how the webprofiler gets injected:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/WebProfilerBundle/EventListener/WebDebugToolbarListener.php#L93-L121

It is possible to do it in a OOP way with Symfony's DomCrawler http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html but for performance reasons I can't recommend it!!